# Installing CUDA toolkit

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit, nvidia-optimus, cuda

I am trying to set up my computer for CUDA development as per [this instruction](http://tryknowdo.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/cuda-5-0-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04/). Before installation it recommends uninstalling nvidia drivers and suggest running `apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"`. But this command will also remove ubuntu-desktop. Is this safe? I don't want to fall in bigger mess while solving smaller problems.

My laptop runs ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, Nvidia gt325M, optimus graphics card.

Please also take a note is the instruction good enough or not. I know optimus makes serious trouble with linux and I want to play on safe side here.

Comment: my installation was successful, removal of ubuntu-desktop was not needed.

Comment: Would you please update..You can answer your own question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling ubuntu-desktop wasn't necessary. The installation was successful.

Comment: In 12.04 also removal of drivers wasn't necesarry if nvidia current was used.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is a meta-package. So uninstalling it would not cause any harm either